# my text is arabic. and text separate in column to half above another half . and go on the next row text and take foreground of next column text

Tags: gridview

my text is arabic. and text separate in column to half above another half . and go on the next row text and take foreground of next column text i am just start programming a week so please explain simple sorry for bad English

```
enter code here
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutButons"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_bacgrounds"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMainOne"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:numColumns="5"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:id="@+id/gridWiewInfo"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textDirection="rtl">
        </GridView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="13"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <GridView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:columnWidth="100dp"
                android:numColumns="5"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:id="@+id/gridViewAllInfo"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textDirection="rtl">
            </GridView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <GridView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:columnWidth="100dp"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:id="@+id/gridViewAvgKol"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textDirection="rtl"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/main_bacgrounds"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMainTwo"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/exit"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonExit" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
                    android:text="@string/moadel_termi"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonGoToAvg" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
                    android:text="@string/delete_dars"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonGoToDeleteDars"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
                    android:text="@string/download_nemoone_soal"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonQuestionSample"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/akhbar"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonNews" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/bayad_bedanid"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonYouMustKnow"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the arabic text is wrapping incorrectly?

Comment: its like this  ال\nله
and go to next column text